# How show the values into fields from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<?php

include 'header.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];


?>
```

```
                                        <form action="" method="post" id="validation-form" class="form-horizontal" enctype='multipart/form-data' >

                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="file">Change Image</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input type="file"  name="file" id="imgae" value="<?php echo $image;?>">
                                                </div>                                                
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="name">Change Name</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input type="text" class="input-large" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label" for="message">Change Description</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <textarea class="span4" name="message" id="message" rows="4"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="controls">
                                               <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>>
                                                <input type='submit' class="btn btn-danger btn" name='but_upload' value="Submit" >
                                                <!--                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn">Validate</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;-->
                                                <a href="elements.php" class="btn"> back </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

code for edititng data

```
    $time_stamp = time();
        $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $image = $time_stamp . '_' . $image;
        $target_dir = "img/upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");
        $location = 'img/upload/'.$image;
        if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'img/upload/'.$image);
        }


     $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
     $query = "insert into images(image,location,name,message) values('$image', '$location', '$name', '$message')";
     mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    echo "<script>document.location.href='elements.php?msg=Updated'</script>";

     <!-- -->
```

Code for updating data

```
     $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
     $query = "UPDATE images SET image = '$image', location = '$location', name = '$name', message = '$message' where id = '$id'";
     mysqli_query($con,$query);


    echo "<script>document.location.href='elements.php?msg=Updated' </script>"  ;

}

 include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

This is the code for adding and updating of data into the database. Using this code I can add or edit data into the database. I can't edit data successfully into the database but the problem was data not showing in the insert fields when I was trying to update it so please help to show the data in the insert fields while updating the data.

Comment: Feel like updating your question to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='1'";
$result =mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  ?>
By using this code on the top of the page then we can show the values in the fields and able to update the existing data
```

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); helps to search from the data base and gives the row which wanted to get and displays 
By replacing rowname with the required row name in here   given in database shows the data from the database

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: sir this explanation was ok or need more explanation for this

Comment: By using the above code wwe can get data from database